# What is the unix/linux way to divide the number of lines contained from two different files?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a file and I am processing it line by line and producing another file with the result. I want to monitor the percentage of completion. In my case, it is just the number of lines in the new file divide by the number of lines from the input file. A simple example would be:

```
$ cat infile
unix
is
awesome

$ cat infile | process.sh >> outfile &
```

Now, if I run my command, I should get 0.33 if `process.sh` completed the first line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you would need to read the file twice, to know how many lines were in it.

Comment: Use `wc -l` command to get the number of lines of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bc:

```
echo "scale=2; $(cat outfile | wc -l) / $(cat infile | wc -l) * 100" | bc
```

In addition, combine this with watch for updated progress:

```
watch -d "echo \"scale=2; \$(cat outfile | wc -l) / \$(cat infile | wc -l) * 100\" | bc"
```

Comment: I like how you multiplied by 100; I used sed  :P

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) for progress (in debian/ubuntu inside package `pv`):

```
pv -l -s `wc -l file.txt` file.txt | process.sh
```

This will use number of lines for progress.
Or you can use just the number of bytes:

```
pv file.txt | process.sh
```

The above commands will show you the percentage of completion and ETA.

Comment: This is probably the best answer. But it requires me to install pv.

Answer (score 0):

```
TOTAL_LINES=`wc -l infile`
LINES=`wc -l outfile`
PERCENT=`echo "scale=2;${LINES}/${TOTAL_LINES}" | bc | sed -e 's_^\.__'`
echo "${PERCENT} % Complete"
```

`scale=2` means you get two significant digits.